# How to open ports in amazon (AWS) Lightsail?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I try to open a port in my instance of AWS Lightsail to be able to raise an application in NodeJs. Enable the Firewall rules as seen in the image.

[image]

but when I run `sudo nmap -sT -O localhost` I can see that the port is closed.

[image]

The port that I try to open is 4000. UFW is inactive. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Two problems: By default, nmap only checks 1000 of the most commonly used ports.  Does it even check 4000?  Also, `localhost` traffic is not affected by the Lightsail firewall.  All of `localhost` is always accessible, so nmap would not prove anything.

Comment: The nodejs app might not be listening on the localhost interface. Check what address the nodejs app is binding to and check if the port is open there. Also like michael-sqlbot metioned: nmap might not even be looking at that port; use the -p option to nmap to list ports to scan.

Answer (score 3):

The firewall and port settings are listed in the Networking tab of your instance's management page in the Amazon Lightsail console. Choose Edit rules or Add another to change or create rules.

More info:

[Amazon Lightsail Info](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail)

Comment: in effect I added the port I need there and still when I run nmap I get the port is closed and therefore I can not raise my application in that port.

Comment: Check the docs, that port your trying to open (4000) might not be allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Manage Section
[image]

Next go to the Networking Tab and add or edit the rules to open up the ports

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Has this issue been resolved?  I have the exact same problem with a Windows 2019 Server.

The Firewall settings are okay as I am trying to use one of the defaults (HTTP - TCP - 80 - all IP addresses).

When I run the above following netstat command...
netstat -nao | find "80"

I get this:

TCP   0.0.0.0:49667   0.0.0.0:0                  LISTENING          1180
TCP [::]:49667   [::]:0                          LISTENING          1180
TCP [{Ipv6 address}   [2001:{macaddress]:80      TIME_WAIT    0
UDP 127.0.0.1:64919       127.0.0.1: 64919                           1180

see here for screenshot:  https://www.screencast.com/t/p29AhyDI4

It appears the only reference to port 80 is against the MAC address, and that states "TIME_WAIT".

I dont understand why the port remains closed on this new Lightsale Windows Server when the Firewall settings have been applied correctly?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/557102)